# Search Algorithms used by top engines?

Tags: engines, software, chess-algorithms

what are the top parallel search algorithms used by top engines ,and which one is the best ?
And is there a reference implementation of them in any programming language ? I know most of  the top engines are open source but they tend to be extremely complex and unsuitable for learning .

Comment: "This question is a bit board,…" that's the most in-character typo I have read in a while. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Best performing algorithms are YBWC and DTS. Lazy SMP is probably giving best performance/complexity ratio. You can read more about parallel search algorithms [here](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Parallel+Search) (make sure to check referencies and links. 
As for reference realization, I haven't seen any, so I just used simpler engines with parallel search,  and, mostly, algorithms descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

For most engines, this is proprietary information. However, Stockfish is quite good and is open source; its search algorithm is found [here](https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/blob/master/src/search.cpp)

Answer (score 0):

You can read all about chess programming [here](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com).

In general, chess engines start with some form of minimax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning, then add in refinements.